# Как сделать проверку

Tags: python, python-3.x, словарь

Всем привет у меня есть такой вот код

```
convert = {'A': 'ALT N6 N5', 'B': 'ALT N6 N6', 'C': 'ALT N6 N7', 'D': 'ALT N6 N8', 'E': 'ALT N6 N9', 'F': 'ALT N7 N0',
               'G': 'ALT N7 N1', 'H': 'ALT N7 N2', 'I': 'ALT N7 N3', 'J': 'ALT N7 N4', 'K': 'ALT N7 N5', 'L': 'ALT N7 N6',
               'M': 'ALT N7 N7', 'N': 'ALT N7 N8', 'O': 'ALT N7 N9', 'P': 'ALT N8 N0', 'Q': 'ALT N8 N1', 'R': 'ALT N8 N2',
               'S': 'ALT N8 N3', 'T': 'ALT N8 N4', 'U': 'ALT N8 N5', 'V': 'ALT N8 N6', 'W': 'ALT N8 N7', 'X': 'ALT N8 N8',
               'Y': 'ALT N8 N9', 'Z': 'ALT N9 N0', 'a': 'ALT N9 N7', 'b': 'ALT N9 N8', 'c': 'ALT N9 N9',
               'd': 'ALT N1 N0 N0', 'e': 'ALT N1 N0 N1', 'f': 'ALT N1 N0 N2', 'g': 'ALT N1 N0 N3', 'h': 'ALT N1 N0 N4',
               'i': 'ALT N1 N0 N5', 'j': 'ALT N1 N0 N6', 'k': 'ALT N1 N0 N7', 'l': 'ALT N1 N0 N8', 'm': 'ALT N1 N0 N9',
               'n': 'ALT N1 N1 N0', 'o': 'ALT N1 N1 N1', 'p': 'ALT N1 N1 N2', 'q': 'ALT N1 N1 N3', 'r': 'ALT N1 N1 N4',
               's': 'ALT N1 N1 N5', 't': 'ALT N1 N1 N6', 'u': 'ALT N1 N1 N7', 'v': 'ALT N1 N1 N8', 'w': 'ALT N1 N1 N9',
               'x': 'ALT N1 N2 N0', 'y': 'ALT N1 N2 N1', 'z': 'ALT N1 N2 N2', ',': 'ALT N4 N4', '.': 'ALT N4 N6',
               '/': 'ALT N4 N7', '<': 'ALT N6 N0', '>': 'ALT N6 N2', '?': 'ALT N6 N3', ';': 'ALT N5 N9', ':': 'ALT N5 N8',
               '"': 'ALT N3 N4', '[': 'ALT N9 N1', ']': 'ALT N9 N3', '{': 'ALT N1 N2 N3', '}': 'ALT N1 N2 N5', }
    
    stEng = input("Введите текст для конвертирования на английском: ")
    
    i = 0
    
    for k in stEng:
        print(convert[stEng[i]])
        i+=1`
```

когда пишу слово hello у меня появляется это слово напечатанное в alt кодах как на скриншоте

[image: код]

я не могу сделать обратную проверку то есть я хотел что бы рядом с alt кодом печаталась та буква которой она соответствует в словаре допустим

```
ALT N1 N0 N4 = h 

ALT N1 N0 N1 = e
```

и так далее объясните как это проделать

Comment: Про какие проверки идет речь? Здесь не видно никаких проверок, они обычно делаются в операторе `if`. Если написать так: `print(convert[stEng[i]], '=', stEng[i])`, то получится то, что вам нужно?

Answer (score 1):

такой вариант вас устраивает?

```
for k in stEng:
    print(f"{convert[k]} = {k}")
```

**P.S.**

кстати зачем вы еще и индекс считаете, когда вы сразу получаете значение?

**P.P.S.**

на всякий случай надо было бы учесть в функции ситуацию когда буква отсутствует:

например так:

```
stEng = 'Ура hello' #input("Введите текст для конвертирования на английском: ")

for k in stEng:
    print(f"{convert.get(k, '*')} = {k}")
```

результат:

```
* = У
* = р
* = а
* =  
ALT N1 N0 N4 = h
ALT N1 N0 N1 = e
ALT N1 N0 N8 = l
ALT N1 N0 N8 = l
ALT N1 N1 N1 = o
```

Comment: спасибо вы решили мой вопрос не могли бы вы объяснить что делает этот код for k in stEng:
    print(f"{convert.get(k, '*')} = {k}")

Comment: словарь `convert` содержит пары {ключ-значение}, чтобы получить значение по ключу вы делаете так `convert[key]`, а что если у вас нет в словаре пары с таким ключом? программа тогда выдаст ошибку, а если не надо ошибку, если надо обработать ситуацию и когда нет ключа - тогда можно сначала проверить есть ли ключ `if key in convert` и потом уже выдать или по ключу значение из словаря или какое-то значение по умолчанию. Чтобы не писать много строчек кода в питоне есть в словаре метод который это делает в 1 строчку - `.get(key, default)` - он выдает значение по ключу или если ключа нет, то default